# ASP.net default resource file handling - best practice?

Tags: asp.net, resources, localization, resource-files

i have a piece of code in my ASP.NET that is depend on the culture/uiCulture that the user is coming from to load few connection string values (right now, we have two, en-US and de-DE resources files).

In my globalization, i set the following two properties:
enableClientBasedCulture="true" culture="auto:en-US" uiCulture="auto:en"

which (from what i understand), means that the application will using the client culture, and the default one (in case its not found) should be en-US, meaning, that if a user comes from france, hence, culture should be fr-FR), and i don't have a resource file that is dedicated to it, it would load the en-US.

resourceManager = new ResourceManager("MyDLL.Properties.Resources", Assembly.GetCallingAssembly());

what i get is:
"Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture or the neutral culture".

Can anyone explain me what do i do wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: found the problem, i was trying to load it from the wrong assembly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on where you are calling your code, the culture might not be set yet. 
When you are calling the code you mentioned, what are the values of the following?

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture
```

Answer (score 0):

found the problem, i was trying to load it from the wrong assembly.